# Is stinky tofu safe to eat

Tags: food-safety, fermentation, chinese-cuisine, smell, tofu

How safe is stinky tofu since it does smell like feces? Is there risk of bad prep when making it or coming out of places with questionable food safety practice?

Comment: Counter question: Why would you *want* to eat something that you perceive as revolting?

Comment: Hi, it seems that you are assuming that food safety is connected to smell. I am closing as a duplicate of one of our basic food safety questions, but the more pertinent information is probably in the tag description, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info.

Comment: Lots of cheeses taste revolting for many people, and they are safe to eat.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  I think @rumtscho assumes it's tofu that's gone bad, while [Stinky tofu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinky_tofu) usually refers to a deliberately-fermented food.

Comment: @ChrisH I did not misunderstand it to be tofu that's gone bad. I understood the question such as: the OP checks food "by nose" and if it still smells good, they declare it "safe". Since "stinky tofu" smells unusually, they are asking by what criteria to determine whether a given piece of tofu is "safe". Since our site uses the official definition of food safety, the only answer we can give is to follow the official rules of food safety. The question I linked has a basic explanation of how food safety is determined without smell, and the tag info explains why smell cannot be used.

Comment: @rumtscho it's meant to smell like that.  There's no suggestion that it's been improperly stored, just a worry about the prep, i.e. it can't be a duplicate of a storage question as it stands.  It could be answered with a pointer to those food safety rules, as we do for prep-related safety.  It's just like saying "I hate the smell of blue cheese, is it safe?" - that's not about  storage

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126462/discussion-on-question-by-pi-a-is-stinky-tofu-safe-to-eat).

Comment: @Pi A: hey, if you want to ask an acceptable version of this question, it would be something like "Are there specific food preparation risks associated with preparing Stinky Tofu that I should watch out for?"  Food safety is on-topic for SA, but your question is too vague and confusing to be answerable.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question: You can't know without sending a sample to a lab.

Your safest course of action is to ditch it.

There are safe bacteria in food and there are unsafe bacteria in food, and it's not easy to establish which bacteria has contaminated your food.

The various food (and drugs) administrations around the world have established certain safety procedures. [This answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/46650/641) might help you.

Comment: That's like saying that the safest thing that you can do with a Camembert is to send it to a lab or ditch it because it smells like fart. People have been eating chòu dòufu for centuries and it does not seem to be less safe than any other food.

Comment: @Daniel, Camembert is supposed to stink, so that's not a valid objection. I was not aware of the existence of chòu dòufu which is a valid objection.